# Usage of an adjective - Presumptuous

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Would it be correct to use the adjective "presumptuous" in the following independent sentence: "They are presumptuous"

or is it required that the context is more defined such as  "They are presumptuous because they felt their nation was greater.. "

Do you necessarily need to define why someone or something is presumptuous or could you use it without giving any context?  If so, how do you tell when an adjective requires the context or when it doesn't?  There's no indication from types of adjectives: positive, comparative, superlative...

Comment: When is there an indication of type of adjective for adjectives with three or more syllables?? More + x or most +x. Any adjective can be used like that. X are [adjective]. Do you need context to write: They are poor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to give context when describing anyone[thing] as anything but context often helps. You know when to give context because the situation demands a context be given for proper communication to occur, declaring someone presumptuous need not require a context a conversation might go something like:

> Q:"Why don't you like them?"
>
> A:"They are presumptuous"

No context of apparent presumptive behaviour is needed. On the other hand if asked *why* one thinks someone presumptuous context is needed.